# Simplificar Codigo

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy armando un formulario donde quiero mostrar los errores que se generen en la validacion debajo de cada campo.

Actualmente estoy colocando el siguiente bloque de codigo debajo de cada campo.

Hay alguna forma de simplificar esto? Porque veo que son muchas lineas para mostrar un simple error.

```
@if ($errors->has('legajo'))
    <small class="form-text text-danger">
     {{ $errors->first('legajo') }}
    </small>
@endif
```

Comment: Por favor tu cófigo como texto

Comment: Ya lo edite, en un principio no me dejaba ponerlo como texto asi que tuve que recurrir a la imagen. Lo lamento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion fue la siguiente. Crear un bloque de codigo

```
@if ($errors->has($input))
 <small class="form-text text-danger">
   {{ $errors->first($input) }}
 </small>
@endif
```

Y luego desde la vista pasar ese parametro mediante un include

```
@include('partial.error', ['input' => 'legajo'])
```